# PayPal METHOD = DoDirectPayment #10501 error

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

followed Andrew angell's great vid on implementing PayPal pro on website -

It worked this afternoon (ACK = success), came back - now getting this error -

"This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration."

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2016-06-02T15:16:25Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 202cf7f63d428
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 000000
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 10.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

According to PayPal here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/#dodirectpayment-processor-response-codes

"Occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive."

None of the older solutions worked as there is no "Merchant Services" in the current interface - I cant seem to locate the place in the sandbox where to enable / accept this billing agreement - is this a paypal bug?

Fyi my sandbox account has been upgraded to Pro -

Comment: fyi - i cloned the sandbox Business-Pro account in the sandbox (upgraded clone to Pro) and the call worked for the first call - and then failed again after 2nd attempt. This behaviour is indeed odd... and making it VERY hard to continue testing!